# React submit to Flask POST method not writing to database (using Axios)

Tags: mysql, reactjs, flask, axios, flask-sqlalchemy

I am running a very simple React app communicating to a Flask app, reading and writing to a MySQL database. I am trying to start with a simple web page where you type text into a textbox, click the button, and this writes in the database with a new entry.

Problem is, I cannot get the text to pass from the React app into the database.

Here is my Flask app:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import request
from flask_cors import CORS


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:password@localhost/testdb'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False, nullable=False)

@app.route('/signup', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        json_data = request.get_json()
        addData = Person(name=json_data.get('name'))
        db.session.add(addData)
        db.session.commit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Here is my signup.jsx file so far:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './signup.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class Signup extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: ''
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event){
        this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
    }

    handleSubmit(event){
        alert('test');
        event.preventDefault(); //What is this?
        const name = {
            name: this.state.name
        };
        alert(JSON.stringify(name));
        axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/signup`, {name})
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            console.log(res.data);
            alert(this.state.name);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            alert(err);
        });
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className='signup'>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input type='text' name='name' onChange={this.handleChange}/><br/>
                    <input type='submit' value='Submit'/>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Signup;
```

I have run this, and it work:

```
eg = Person(name='what')
db.session.add(eg)
db.session.commit()
```

It's not a read/write nor a connection problem; it seems to be a coding error.

I get this message when I click the Submit:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Feb/2019 00:22:26] "OPTIONS /signup HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

However, when I query the table in MySQL Workbench, there is no new data.

The React app runs on localhost:3000 and the Flask app runs on http://127.0.0.1:5000/

Where a I going wrong?

EDIT
I edited my code and added some alerts and prints. When I print from the signup() method, nothing ever prints.
In the handleSubmit function, I always get an error alerting saying that there is a 'Error: Network Error'

EDIT
I added CORS to the Flask application. The data gets written, but Axios gives a 500 code in Flask:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Feb/2019 20:59:31] "POST /signup HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: Hi, can you try this `req_name = request.form['name']` and then do `addData = Person(name=req_name)` ? I am referencing from here : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_http_methods.htm

Comment: That didn't work

Comment: I get an error alerting saying that there is a 'Error: Network Error', and axios.post doesn't seem to happen at all.

Comment: in your post i can see this line `127.0.0.1 - - [19/Feb/2019 00:22:26] "OPTIONS /signup HTTP/1.1" 200 -` which i am assuming is from backend server log, so i guess axios call was working earlier. Is that right? Also, dont know if this is the issue or not(most likely not), can you use proper single quotes in `axios.pos`t instead of accent character you have used.

Comment: @ArpitAgrawal I tried double quotes and it still gives the same problem. The 200 code from the backend server still happens, but no data gets written to the database, and I get the Network Error on Axios.

Comment: @ArpitAgrawal I edited my code to include CORS in the flask app. The data writes, but now Axios gives me a 500 code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was receiving a network error. I had to enable CORS in order to get my transactions to work.

```
handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const name = {
        name: this.state.name
    };
    axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/signup`, {name})
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        alert(err); //See this error
    });
}

from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import request
from flask_cors import CORS


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
```

Answer (score 0):

Axios sends by default data as [json](https://github.com/axios/axios/#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format). So you need to get the data in Flask from the request body as a [JSON object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/testing/#testing-json-apis).

```py
from flask import request

@app.route('/signup', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        json_data = request.get_json()
        addData = Person(name=json_data.get('name'))
        db.session.add(addData)
        db.session.commit()
```